# while installing caffe in ubuntu15.04, undefined reference to `lzma_index_buffer_decode'

Tags: ubuntu, caffe

I want to install caffe in the ubuntu, I have already installed cudnn/cuda/anaconda/openCV. But when I  `make all -j4` under the caffe-master folder, it shows

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to lzma_index_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to lzma_index_size@XZ_5.0 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference  to lzma_index_uncompressed_size@XZ_5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to lzma_stream_footer_decode@XZ_5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to lzma_index_end@XZ_5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8: undefined reference to lzma_stream_buffer_decode@XZ_5.0
```

Anyone could tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually try export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Comment: Well! perfect! Thanks a lot! It works!

Comment: adding my comment as an answer. Please accept @Stvegao

Answer (score 0):

Actually try export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/